# Google map shows output only when code is debugged

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google map v2 code which shows multiple markers on a route returned from google api on the device's screen.

The desired output is seen only when the code is debugged.

But when i run the same code on the same device i see a blank screen.

Please help me out.

I have tried : 
1) uninstalling and then re-installing the app
2) clean and rebuild the project
3) restarting the device and location permissions
4) restarting android studio and trying again.
5) Keeping and removing breakpoints.

But nothing worked.Need help !!

Here is my code >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> markers = new ArrayList<>();
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker1,mCurrLocationMarker2;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    FrameLayout mainFrameLayout;
    Snackbar snackbar;

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 1;
    String stringIMEI = "",stringLatitudeOrigin = "",stringLongitudeOrigin = "",
            stringLatitudeDest = "",stringRoute = "",stringCurrentDate = "";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current time =&gt; "+c.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        stringCurrentDate = df.format(c.getTime());

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mainFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainFrameLayout);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }else {
            TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            stringIMEI = mngr.getDeviceId().toString();
        }

        GetRouteVolleyRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private String getUrl(ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints) {
        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "",str_dest = "",waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true|",key = "",parameters = "",output = "",url = "";
        if (MarkerPoints.size() >= 2) {
            for (int i = 0;i < MarkerPoints.size();i++) {
                LatLng latlng = MarkerPoints.get(i);
                if (i == 0) {
                    str_origin = "origin=" + latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude;
                }
                if (i == MarkerPoints.size()-1) {
                    str_dest = "destination=" + latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude;
                } else {
                    waypoints = waypoints + latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude + "|";
                }
            }
             key = "MYKEY";
            // Building the parameters to the web service
             parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + key;//+ waypoints + "&"
            // Output format
             output = "json";
            // Building the url to the web service
             url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
        }
        return url;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String data = "";
            try {
                HttpConnection http = new HttpConnection();
                data = http.downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }
    }
    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {
        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                if (!jObject.equals("")){
                    //save route api call
                    stringRoute = jObject.toString();
                    //SaveRouteVolleyRequest(jObject.toString());
                    }
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }
        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            lineOptions.width(8);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    points.add(position);
                }
                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);

            }
            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            if(points.size()!=0)mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setExpirationDuration(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1f);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) { }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        mMap.clear();
        if (mCurrLocationMarker1 != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker1.remove();
        }
        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        stringLatitudeOrigin = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        stringLongitudeOrigin = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        mCurrLocationMarker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Your device"));
        for (int i = 0;i < MarkerPoints.size();i++) {
            LatLng latlng = MarkerPoints.get(i);
            if (i == 0) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(markers.get(i)));
            }
            if (i == MarkerPoints.size()-1) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(markers.get(i)));
            } else {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(markers.get(i)));
            }
        }

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14.0f));

        if (isConnectingToInternet(MainActivity.this) == true) {
//            SaveLocationVolleyRequest();
        }else{snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, "No Internet Connection,Please Verify", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) { }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }else {
                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, "permission denied", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
                return;
            }
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE : {
                if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    stringIMEI = mngr.getDeviceId().toString();
                }else {
                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, "permission denied", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            } // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }

    public void SaveLocationVolleyRequest(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.LOCATIONAPI_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (json.getString("success").equals("1")) {
                                snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, json.getString("msg"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                                TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                snackbar.show();

                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("device_id", json.getString("device_id"));
                                editor.commit();

                                SaveRouteVolleyRequest();
                            }else {
                                snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout,json.getString("msg"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                                TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                snackbar.show();

                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("device_id", json.getString("device_id"));
                                editor.commit();

                                SaveRouteVolleyRequest();
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException je){
                            je.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, error.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                        TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                        mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
              Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("driverid",sharedPreferences.getString("user_id",""));
                params.put("latitude",stringLatitudeOrigin);
                params.put("longitude",stringLongitudeOrigin);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void SaveRouteVolleyRequest(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.SAVEROUTEAPI_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (json.getString("success").equals("1")) {
                                snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, json.getString("msg"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                                TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                snackbar.show();
                            }else {
                                snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout,"No Co-ordinates due to"+json.getString("msg"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                                TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                snackbar.show();
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException je){
                            je.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, error.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                        TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                        mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("device_id",sharedPreferences.getString("device_id",""));
                params.put("route",stringRoute);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void GetRouteVolleyRequest(){
        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Fetching Route !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.GETROUTEAPI_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            LatLng origin = null;
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (json.getString("success").equals("1")) {
                                JSONArray routearray = new JSONArray(json.getString("route"));
                                for (int i=0;i<routearray.length();i++) {
                                    JSONObject routeObj = routearray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    if (i == 0)
                                        origin = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(routeObj.getString("latitude")),
                                                Double.parseDouble(routeObj.getString("longitude")));

                                    MarkerPoints.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(routeObj.getString("latitude")),
                                            Double.parseDouble(routeObj.getString("longitude"))));

                                    markers.add(routeObj.getString("drop_name"));
                                }
                                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                                    String url = getUrl(MarkerPoints);
                                    Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
                                    FetchUrl fetchUrl = new FetchUrl();
                                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                                    fetchUrl.execute(url);
                                }
                            else {
                                snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout,json.getString("msg"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                                TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                snackbar.show();
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException je){
                            je.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, error.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                        TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                        mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("userid",sharedPreferences.getString("user_id",""));
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity=(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo info[]=connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if(info!=null)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<info.length;i++)
                    if(info[i].getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                        return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide snippet of code.

Comment: This sounds strange to me.  Assuming you have no breakpoints, your map activity should behave largely the same whether or not it is connected to Android Studio in the background.  Are you certain the app behaves correctly when in debug mode?

Comment: My guess is that you added objects on the map before it finished rendering, while in debug mode you linger for a few seconds and let it render. Please provide your relevant code.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I don't have a release API key (I think), and it works for me with or without the debugger.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen forget what I said, I misread "debugging" as "debug" -- as in, running a debug apk vs a release apk

Comment: @TimCastelijns It's a good guess...this shouldn't be happening in my experience.  Ironically, running the app in debug mode is the first thing I would do.

Comment: Please find the code  that i have mentioned in he edited question. Also thank you for your prompt responses

Comment: please remove everything that is not related to google maps or the issue at hand

Comment: ok but that wont help..since im taking marker points from my server so that api call is needed..and then im saving the google route received on my server

Answer (score 0):

Just check in google console that in you account more than 1 Api Key are add if added please remove those API key which you are not using currently.

Comment: yup there is only one api key for google maps android api